# Uncaught TypeError: number is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator) - Error with Object Detection App Tutorial

Tags: reactjs, tensorflow, object-detection

I am following this tutorial for building an object detection application using Tensorflow JS and React JS: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTSRZt04JkY&t=1474s. Despite having the exact same code, I got this error and found out that boxes[i] in utilities.js is not an array of 4 values but rather a single number.

Here is the full error (number changes based on the prediction):

> Uncaught TypeError TypeError: number 26 is not iterable (cannot read
> property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
> at drawRect (c:\Users\Aswin.Surya24\RealTimeObjectDetection\asl-app\src\utilities.js:39:1)
> at  (c:\Users\Aswin.Surya24\RealTimeObjectDetection\asl-app\src\App.js:65:1)
> --- requestAnimationFrame ---
> at detect (c:\Users\Aswin.Surya24\RealTimeObjectDetection\asl-app\src\App.js:65:1)
> --- await ---
> at  (c:\Users\Aswin.Surya24\RealTimeObjectDetection\asl-app\src\App.js:24:1)
> --- setInterval ---
> at runCoco (c:\Users\Aswin.Surya24\RealTimeObjectDetection\asl-app\src\App.js:23:1)
> --- await ---
> at  (c:\Users\Aswin.Surya24\RealTimeObjectDetection\asl-app\src\App.js:76:1)
> at commitHookEffectListMount (c:\Users\Aswin.Surya24\RealTimeObjectDetection\asl-app\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:23150:1)
> at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (c:\Users\Aswin.Surya24\RealTimeObjectDetection\asl-app\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:24926:1)
> at commitPassiveMountEffects_complete (c:\Users\Aswin.Surya24\RealTimeObjectDetection\asl-app\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:24891:1)
> at commitPassiveMountEffects_begin (c:\Users\Aswin.Surya24\RealTimeObjectDetection\asl-app\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:24878:1)
> at commitPassiveMountEffects (c:\Users\Aswin.Surya24\RealTimeObjectDetection\asl-app\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:24866:1)
> at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (c:\Users\Aswin.Surya24\RealTimeObjectDetection\asl-app\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:27039:1)
> at flushPassiveEffects (c:\Users\Aswin.Surya24\RealTimeObjectDetection\asl-app\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:26984:1)
> at  (c:\Users\Aswin.Surya24\RealTimeObjectDetection\asl-app\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:26769:1)
> at workLoop (c:\Users\Aswin.Surya24\RealTimeObjectDetection\asl-app\node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:266:1)
> at flushWork (c:\Users\Aswin.Surya24\RealTimeObjectDetection\asl-app\node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:239:1)
> at performWorkUntilDeadline (c:\Users\Aswin.Surya24\RealTimeObjectDetection\asl-app\node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:533:1)
> --- postMessage ---
> at schedulePerformWorkUntilDeadline (c:\Users\Aswin.Surya24\RealTimeObjectDetection\asl-app\node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:574:1)
> at performWorkUntilDeadline (c:\Users\Aswin.Surya24\RealTimeObjectDetection\asl-app\node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:538:1)
> --- postMessage ---
> at schedulePerformWorkUntilDeadline (c:\Users\Aswin.Surya24\RealTimeObjectDetection\asl-app\node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:574:1)
> at requestHostCallback (c:\Users\Aswin.Surya24\RealTimeObjectDetection\asl-app\node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:588:1)
> at unstable_scheduleCallback (c:\Users\Aswin.Surya24\RealTimeObjectDetection\asl-app\node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:441:1)
> at scheduleCallback$1 (c:\Users\Aswin.Surya24\RealTimeObjectDetection\asl-app\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:27537:1)
> at ensureRootIsScheduled (c:\Users\Aswin.Surya24\RealTimeObjectDetection\asl-app\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:25683:1)
> at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (c:\Users\Aswin.Surya24\RealTimeObjectDetection\asl-app\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:25531:1)
> at updateContainer (c:\Users\Aswin.Surya24\RealTimeObjectDetection\asl-app\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:28858:1)
> at ReactDOMHydrationRoot.render.ReactDOMRoot.render (c:\Users\Aswin.Surya24\RealTimeObjectDetection\asl-app\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js:29314:1)
> at ./src/index.js (c:\Users\Aswin.Surya24\RealTimeObjectDetection\asl-app\src\index.js:8:1)
> at options.factory (c:\Users\Aswin.Surya24\RealTimeObjectDetection\asl-app\webpack\runtime\react
> refresh:6:1)
> at **webpack_require** (c:\Users\Aswin.Surya24\RealTimeObjectDetection\asl-app\webpack\bootstrap:24:1)
> at  (c:\Users\Aswin.Surya24\RealTimeObjectDetection\asl-app\webpack\startup:7:1)
> at  (localhost꞉3000/static/js/bundle.js:177811:12)

Here is my drawRect function:

```
//Define a drawing function
export const drawRect = (boxes, classes, scores, threshold, imgWidth, imgHeight, ctx)=>{
    for(let i=0; i<=boxes.length; i++){
        if(boxes[i] && classes[i] && scores[i]>threshold){
            // Extract variables
            //console.log("Boxes:" + boxes[i])
            const [y,x,height,width] = boxes[i]
            
            const text = classes[i]
        
            // Set styling
            ctx.strokeStyle = labelMap[text]['color']
            ctx.lineWidth = 10
            ctx.fillStyle = 'white'
            ctx.font = '30px Arial'         
            
            // DRAW!!
            ctx.beginPath()
            //labelMap[text]['name'] + 
            ctx.fillText(labelMap[text]['name'] + ' - ' + Math.round(scores[i]*100)/100, x*imgWidth, y*imgHeight-10)
            ctx.rect(x*imgWidth, y*imgHeight, width*imgWidth/2, height*imgHeight/1.5);
            ctx.stroke()
        }
    }
}
```

I tested the same model on Jupyter Notebook, and it worked, so I know it's not a problem with the model itself. However, I am not sure if TFJS changed the way it formats its tensors. I did get the 8 tensor values when I run console.log(obj).

I have a feeling that the following code is wrong and it is changed/deprecated, potentially causing my error. When I checked the shape of boxes, it is (1, 100) instead of the expected (4, 100).

```
 const boxes = await obj[1].array()
 const classes = await obj[2].array()
 const scores = await obj[4].array()
```

Can anyone figure out why boxes is not the right shape? I also tried labelMap[text]['color] and that returns a TypeError that labelMap[text] is undefined. When I ran console.log(classes[i]), it outputs a value of tensors instead of the expected integers to use as the indexes of the labelMap. I'm not sure whether the issues are related, but it seems boxes and classes aren't being assigned the right values from obj.

The code in App.js and utilities.js is the exact same as the one in the video. I'd really appreciate any and all help with this!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.